# iTunes App store screenshots for applications that require hardware the simulator doesn't provide

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ios-simulator

I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions here. I have an app that requires bluetooth. I own a few Apple devices, but, I certainly don't have all of them. The usual suggestion is 'use the simulator', but since the simulator doesn't simulate bluetooth, all I get is a big 'Bluetooth unavailable', which is unattractive for the store.

Will Apple accept it if I resize them in Photoshop? I can either use the 6 or the iPad mini, but they will need to be upscaled to iPhone 6+ (potentially losing quality).

Thoughts? Will I need to hunt down users with each device and then walk them through screenshots (seems so impractical)?

Comment: _Will Apple accept it_ - Don't know - we're not Apple. Ask them, and see [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) on [meta]

Comment: To be fair, in this case, there is PLENTY of easy to find precedent. Unless Apple deviates wildly from their past behavior, we pretty much do know what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many popular apps' screenshots are heavily doctored and Photoshopped. If your screenshots are not openly deceptive, you should be fine.

e.g. one of the first apps I checked in the App Store has screenshots which are cropped, framed with custom art, and extra blurbs added on the periphery: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cars-fast-as-lightning/id638218744?mt=8

This one crops the image, adds a blurb on top, and even has a photograph of a phone in a user's hand: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/health-mate-steps-tracker/id542701020?mt=8

These are both featured apps receiving prominent placement on the App Store.